# ERROR: Cannot compile a minimal program. The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, qtembedded

I am following this guide: https://www.interelectronix.com/qt-515-cross-compilation-raspberry-compute-module-4-ubuntu-20-lts.html

But when I do:
../qt-everywhere-src-5.15.2/configure -release -opengl es2 -eglfs -device linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/tools/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5.15 -extprefix ~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/qt5.15 -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtscript -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine -nomake tests -make libs -pkg-config -no-use-gold-linker -v -recheck

I get some errors about includes missing which I fixed but the I get this error I tried many things but I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some relevant files are missing. Go into the sysroot and verify that the step:

```
./sysroot-relativelinks.py sysroot
```

has done its work. You shouldn't see any broken symlink.

Comment: Thank you for the help, however I do not know how I can verify that step. 

The file says: Take a sysroot directory and turn all the abolute symlinks and turn them into relative ones such that the sysroot is usable within another system.

But how do I check this?

Comment: Simply go into the lib directories of the sysroot and check if links are broken. Some symlinks in the sysroot are absolute and therefore may result broken on your host. That script should fix this.

Comment: calling sysroot-relativelinks again did not work for me. is there an intermediary step that needs to happen?

Comment: I'd check that relative links are all fixed.